# What is the unit for modulus of elasticity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, elasticity, stress-strain

I've previously asked a question regarding the modulus of elasticity which I am still unsure about. I've been told various formulae to calculate the modulus of elasticity, some of which give answers with different units to one another. Any help clarifying the correct units would be much appreciated.

Comment: Elastic modulus of a solid material: Pa. Elastic modulus of a spring: N. Note that Robert S Hoy is referring to any elastic modulus for a solid. His unit ($\text{J m}^{-3}$) can be written as $\text{N m}^{-2}$.

Comment: The unit of Young's modulus is psi (pounds force per square inch).

Answer (score 3):

The modulus of elasticity (Young's Modulus) is defined as stress divided by strain in the linear elastic region of the stress strain relation for a material, or

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon}$$

Where $\sigma$ equals the stress. The units for stress can be in various forms.

Non SI (engish) units for stress are typically PSI (pounds per square inch).

The SI unit for stress is the Pascal (Pa). But since 1 Pa = 1 N/m$^2$ the latter can also be used for units of stress.

$\epsilon$ is the strain in units of length per unit length (m/m), so basically it has no units.

So the units for the modulus of elasticity can be expressed as PSI, Pa, or  N/m$^2$. If you multiply the numerator and denominator of N/m$^2$ the unit for modulus of elasticity is then N-m/m$^3$, or J/m$^3$.

But I don't believe J/m$^3$ is typically used for units of the modulus of elasticity. As I understand, the more common unit is the Pascal (Pa).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't that a Pascal, Pa?

Comment: Hi Bob.  Please do me a favor and vote to reopen that 2 box problem.  I found it very interesting and challenging, edited the problem statement to make it more understandable, and offered a solution approach that I would hate to see fall through the cracks.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, 1 Pa = 1 N/m$^2$. In mechanics of solids they use either pounds per square inch (PSI) or Newtons per square meter. But as I understood it, the OP's  issue is how they got energy per cubic meter. That's why I used N'm$^2$.

Comment: @ChetMiller Sure, can you give me a link to it cause I don't remember it.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/617906/2-boxes-linked-with-a-tube-one-gets-heated-what-is-the-ratio-of-the-volumes

Comment: @ChetMiller Done.

Comment: @ChetMiller See my updated answer. It points out, as I think you wanted, that the Pa is the common (non english) unit for the modulus of elasticity. To get from there to energy per cubic meter you need to use the equivalent unit of N/m$^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Elastic moduli are energy densities -- they have units energy/volume.